# best way to implement render props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using render model props, but I think there is a better way to do this, does anyone know another way?

```
{variable === "nameComponen" && <component/>}
{variable === "nameComponen2" && <component2/>}
```

Comment: Have an object of string keys => components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it using ternary operator :

```
{variable === "nameComponen"? <component/>
 :
 variable === "nameComponen2"?<component2/>:<></>
}
```

or you can do it in render method by variable

```
render (){
let dispVar = "";
if(variable === "nameComponen"){
    dispVar = <component/>
}
else if(variable === "nameComponen2" ){
    dispVar = <component2/>
}
```

and in return use it by accessing variable :

```
return(){
<div>
{dispVar }
</div>
```